# Passing values from form to another form

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I am looking for a solution to pass values from a contact form to the next contact form. I think a good way is to show you an example: https://www.zonnepanelen-weetjes.nl/ when you type in a postal code (for example: 2012 ES) it'll pass the rest of the info to the next page https://www.zonnepanelen-weetjes.nl/offerte-formulier/?postalcode=2012+ES

My idea is to have something similar but with the Place Autocomplete Address from Google. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
I know how to implement this function into my plugin (contact form 7) for Wordpress

What I would like is on the first form you can enter the full address with Google autocomplete. Then onto the next form it'll pass the info into their separate fields. As shown in the above link from Google.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction here. I have some basic knowledge of PHP and could perhaps change some of the code the plugin to make this work.

Thanks in advance and I hope I explained myself well enough as I do not know how I would describe this function otherwise.

Greetings,
Mark

---

--EDIT--
**SOLUTION**

As I was looking through the internet I found my own solution to this. I will write the solution here for future reference so other people can read.

You will need these 2 plugins to be installed:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

In form 1 you can add for example

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>
```

In **form 1** go to Redirect Settings and **select a page to redirect** to on successful form submission.

Then either select one of these:
Pass all the fields from the form as URL query parameters
Pass specific fields from the form as URL query parameters

I selected the first one but it will send all parameters, the other one lets you select specific fields but for this demo purpose I passed all fields.

Now in **form 2** do this:

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [dynamictext* your-name "CF7_GET key='your-name'"] </label>
```

That's it, it should work now and you can pass fields from one another.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simple js. use this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  $('#Id1').change(function() {
  $('#Id2').val($(this).val());
 });
  }
</script>
```

Id1- Give this id to contact form field like this. 
`[email* your-email id:Id1"]`

Id2- Give this id to other fields, where you want to show this value. `[email* your-email id:Id2"]`

Add this js into your footer. I think its work for you, try this and let me know.

Comment: Hmmm tried your solution but didn't work me. Maybe I am doing something wrong.
I created two forms in contact form 7, one with `[email* your-email id:Id1]` and in the other form `[email* your-email id:Id2]`  
I then redirected the first form with Id1 to the next page with Id2 but noting happened.    
However I do have the possibility to pass all the fields from the form as URL query parameters. Maybe I can do something with that?

Comment: add this js into the footer and check your console.

Comment: I added your js to the footer and checked in the console no errors but it is still not working.

Comment: Found my own solution, updated my original post to show how I did it. Thanks for the help @Harsh Khare